# Im getting the error "TypeError: xml.getElementsByTagName is not a function"

Tags: javascript, xml

I am getting the error "TypeError: xml.getElementsByTagName is not a function"

the error lies in "var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml,'text/xml');"

how can i fix this ?
i have been working on this for hours on end and still no result

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

   if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
       myFunction(xhttp);
    }
}
xhttp.open("GET", "http://LEMONPIE-PC/erdas-iws/ogc/wms/?service=WMS&request=getcapabilities", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {

    var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml,'text/xml');

    console.log(xmlDoc);

    document.write("<table border='1'>");
    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Layer");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    { 
        document.write("<tr><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Layer")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Style")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td></tr>");
    }
    document.write("</table>");


}



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myFunction(xhttp);  <-- Look at what you are passing to the method
```

You are passing in the XMLHttpRequest object and treating that as the text, when that is not the case. You need to reference the responseText that XMLHttpRequest object holds.

```
myFunction(xhttp.responseText);
```

or if you are fetching XML, I not sure why you are parsing it again since the XMLHttpRequest object will do it for you. It should be available with responseXML as long as it is a valid XML document.

```
myFunction(xhttp.responseXML);
```